# Convert NSString->NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate

I need to convert my NSString in the end to an NSDate but I am having problems doing so. How would I achieve the same functionality with this code while making the end result an NSDate?

```
//Date and Format it
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Thanks!

Edit:

```
//Date and Format it
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *enddate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:enddate forKey:@"theDate"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Thanks, is edit1 in my original post what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Well it seems pretty redundant now. You're creating a date set to now, then converting it to a string, then back to a date. In theory, `now` and `enddate` should be equal. Why are you doing it like this?

Comment: not sure. What should the code look like instead? I understand what you are saying but I am not sure how to apply it to the code.

Comment: Well it looks like you want to store the current date and time in the user defaults. Something like this should work: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSDate date] forKey: @"theDate"];`