# Creating NSDate from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, rfc3339

I have the following `NSString`:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2012-01-24T14:59:01Z";
```

I want to create an `NSDate` from that string. I looked up the `NSDate` Class Reference and thought of using `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:`:

> Creates and returns an `NSDate` object set to the date and time
>   specified by a given string.
>
> `+ (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string`
>
> **Parameters**
>   *string*
>    A string that contains a colloquial specification of a date,
>   such as “last Tuesday at dinner,” “3pm December 31, 2001,” “12/31/01,”
>   or “31/12/01.” 
>   **Return Value**
>   A new `NSDate` object set to the current
>   date and time specified by string.

However, when I'm trying to use it like this:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:dateString];
```

I'm getting the following error:

> No known class method for selector 'dateWithNaturalLanguageString:'

Comment: the doc state that : `It may give unexpected results, and its use is strongly discouraged.`too in the discussion section. Also is `dateString` really a natural language string ? this method isn't part of iOS SDK

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4380381/1114171

Comment: Maybe not... Didn't get the chance to try it anyway. Do you recommend any other solution?

Comment: you probably looked at the wrong doc page, [NSDate iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I wouldn't use the dateWithNaturalLanguageString method, basically the feedback i've gotten is that if it works with those types of strings its purely by accident and shouldn't be counted on to work reliably in future updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). It's an RFC 3339 date-time.

```
- (NSString *)userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString:(NSString *)rfc3339DateTimeString
    // Returns a user-visible date time string that corresponds to the
    // specified RFC 3339 date time string. Note that this does not handle
    // all possible RFC 3339 date time strings, just one of the most common
    // styles.
{
    NSString *          userVisibleDateTimeString;
    NSDateFormatter *   rfc3339DateFormatter;
    NSLocale *          enUSPOSIXLocale;
    NSDate *            date;
    NSDateFormatter *   userVisibleDateFormatter;

    userVisibleDateTimeString = nil;

    // Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.

    rfc3339DateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];

    [rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];
    if (date != nil) {

        // Convert the NSDate to a user-visible date string.

        userVisibleDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        assert(userVisibleDateFormatter != nil);

        [userVisibleDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [userVisibleDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        userVisibleDateTimeString = [userVisibleDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    }
    return userVisibleDateTimeString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

NSDateFormatter class will help you with this problem. And there are many questions about this already, for example, here is the first one: [Convert NSString->NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154477/convert-nsstring-nsdate)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the constructor `dateWithString` constructor or (if that gives you a similar error), try using an `NSDateFormatter` as described [here](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2011/01/ios-101-how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate.html).

Comment: You're right I was looking at the Mac OS X Developer Library instead of the iOS Developer Library. Curses. `NSDateFormatter` it is.

Answer (score 1):

The `dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` class method is only implemented on Mac OS X, not on iOS, that is why you're getting the error.

To achieve what you're looking for, you need the `NSDateFormatter` class.  The class is quite heavy, so you'll want to read the documentation first to understand how best to use it.